# How are PCA and SVD distributed in libraries like MLlib or Mahout

Tags: machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, pca, svd, bigdata

I know techniques for dimensionality reduction like PCA or SVD.

I would like to know how these techniques are implemented in distributed Big Data platforms like Apache Spark.

Is there available a pseudocode or schema with the formulation? I would like to know what parts of the algorithm could cause a bottleneck due to communication issues.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262539/pca-in-spark-mllib-and-spark-ml/40268082#40268082

Comment: My question is partially solved in that question, they explain PCA. They parallelize A'A and then master node compute the eigenvalues with no parallelization. In SVD you decompose your matrix A into three submatrices A=USV'. I understand that the procedure to obtain S and V should be parallelized in the same way than PCA, but what about U?

Comment: If you need U you can obtain it by computing the product AVS^(-1).

Comment: Then I suppose that they broadcast V and S^(-1) and the product is performed in every partition of A. Thanks.

Comment: In mahout there is also dssvd - distributed stochastic singular value decomposition.  It returns two U and V as DRMs (distributed row matrices, which in the spark case are wrappers around RDDs) [link](https://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/d-ssvd.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Mahout implements [Distributed Stochastic Singular Value Decomposition](https://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/d-ssvd.html) which is directly based on [Randomized methods for computing low-rank
approximations of matrices](https://amath.colorado.edu/faculty/martinss/Pubs/2012_halko_dissertation.pdf) by Nathan Halko

Note that `dssvd` is for Apache-Mahout Samsara which is a library that will run on top of Spark.  So in essence this is a Spark based approach to svd which is in fact distributed.

With regard to a distributed PCA, Mahout also exposes distributed stochastic PCA- there has been some website shuffling recently, but the dspca (distributed stochastic Principal component analysis) is given as an example [here](http://mahout.apache.org/users/sparkbindings/home.html) which gives the algorithm and implementation.

Halko I believe (see reference above) also discusses distributed PCA.  I can't tell you where the bottlenecks would be, but I hope this information gets you started in your research.